# Error "ScrollView contentOffset binding has been read"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchos

When using a Picker in my WatchOs-App, I get an Error called "ScrollView contentOffset binding has been read;"

The Picker itself is working with no complaints, but I get the following error and have no clue what to do with it.

> ScrollView contentOffset binding has been read; this will cause grossly inefficient view performance as the ScrollView's content will be updated whenever its contentOffset changes. Read the contentOffset binding in a view that is not parented between the creator of the binding and the ScrollView to avoid this.

> ScrollView contentOffset binding has been read; this will cause grossly inefficient view performance as the ScrollView's content will be updated whenever its contentOffset changes. Read the contentOffset binding in a view that is not parented between the creator of the binding and the ScrollView to avoid this.

It's the same message but I get it twice every time I open the view(it pops up when loading the view)

That's my code:

```
struct FetchWebsiteView: View {
/*@Binding var usernameParent : String
@Binding var passwordParent : String*/
@Binding var developerModeParent : Bool
@Binding var rToken : String
@State var isRunning : Bool = false
@State var projects = [""]
@State private var selectedProject = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Picker("Select a Project", selection: $selectedProject){
            ForEach(projects, id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }.frame(height: 80)
        Spacer()
        if (selectedProject != "" && isRunning == false) {
            Button("Start Time Stamp"){
                print("Time started")
                isRunning = true
            }
        } else if (isRunning == true) {
            Button("Stop Time Stamp") {
                print("Time stopped")
                isRunning = false
                selectedProject = ""
            }
        }
        
        Spacer()
        //Text(selectedProject + "")
        
    }.onAppear{
        Task {
            projects = await doHTTPProjectsCall(token: rToken)
            }
    }
}
```

}